# Create a Linked Server in On-Prem SQL Server to Azure SQL Database using Domain Service Account

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, linked-server

I am trying to connect from a On Prem SQL Server to an Azure SQL Database. We are able to telnet & connect directly but when trying to create a Linked Server it fails if we use Domain Authentication. This works great using SQL Login.

I scrambled across multiple documentation but couldn't find much for authentication using a Domain Service Account.

Would someone know if this works & any documentation on the setup will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for [Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell) with ADFS

Comment: SQL DB doesn't support domain authentication as it is not part of your domain... so, it won't work.  Linked servers don't directly test AAD-based auth, but you'd have to supply a password in that path as well since your on-premises SQL Server doesn't know about your AAD environment either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Conor Cunningham MSFT for the comment, posting it as the answer.

SQL DB doesn't support domain authentication as it is not part of your domain and Linked servers don't directly take AAD auth, you will have to supply a password as well.

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#active-directory-integrated-authentication) for more information.